# Which tool/server can be used to perform continuous integration with PHPUNIt, Selenium Test and other code bash code

Tags: continuous-integration

Which tool/server can be used to perform  continuous integration  that helps running PHP UNIT tests,  SELENIUM tests  and Custom tests such as  bash script ideally. I have got following options:
1. Hudson
2. PHP Under COntrol (plugin of cruise control)
3. jenkins
4. Bamboo (Atlassian)
5. TeamCity (JetBrains)
6. Apache Continuum

I need to know which is the best in my case, with some reasons. I appreciate your valuable thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe look at [Sismo](http://sismo.sensiolabs.org/) (from the Symfony folks) ?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is best option for your problem. Currently we are also using jenkins as our CI server and we are running unit tests, selenium tests and other tests including load testing etc. with jenkins. Also it has support for multiple plugins.